# In Excel 2007, how can I SUMIFS indices of multiple columns from a named range?

Tags: excel, indices, named-ranges, sumifs

I am analysing library statistics relating to loans made by particular user categories.  The loan data forms the named range LoansToApril2013.  Excel 2007 is quite happy for me to use an index range as the sum range in a SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,3),10,INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,4):INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,6))
```

Here 10 indicates a specific user category, and this sums loans made to that group from three columns.  By "index range" I'm referring to the

```
INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,4):INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,6)
```

sum_range value.

However, if I switch to using a SUMIFS to add further criteria, Excel returns a #VALUE error if an index range is used.  It will only accept a single index.

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,4),INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,3),1,INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,1),"PTFBL")
```

works fine

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,4):INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,6),INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,3),1,INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,1),"PTFBL")
```

returns #value, and I'm not sure why.

Interestingly,

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,4):INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,4),INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,3),1,INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,1),"PTFBL")
```

is also accepted and returns the same as the first one with a single index.

I haven't been able to find any documentation or comments relating to this.  Does anyone know if there is an alternative structure that would allow SUMIFS to conditionally sum index values from three columns?  I'd rather not use three separate formulae and add them together, though it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

The `sumifs` formula is modelled after an array formula  and comparisons in the `sumifs` need to be the same size, the last one mimics a single column in the `LoansToApril2013` array column `4:4` is column 4.

The second to bottom one is 3 columns wide and the comparison columns are 1 column wide causing the error.

Comment: Huh.  That never occurred to me - to be honest it seems an very peculiar thing for Excel to complain about, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

`sumifs` can't do that, but `sumproduct` can

Example:

```
X  1  1  1
Y  2  2  2
Z  3  3  3
```

starting in A1

the formula `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A3="X")*B1:D3)` gives the answer `3`, and altering the value `X` in the formula to `Y` or `Z` changes the returned value to the appropriate sum of the lines.
Note that this will **not** work if you have text in the area - it will return `#VALUE!`

If you can't avoid the text, then you need an array formula. Using the same example, the formula would be `=SUM(IF(A1:A3="X",B1:D3))`, and to enter it as an array formula, you need to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to enter the formula - you should notice that excel puts **{ }** around the formula. It treats any text as zero, so it will successfully add up the numbers it finds even if you have text in one of the boxes (e.g. change one of the `1`'s in the example to be `blah` and the total will be 2 - the formula will add the two remaining `1`s in the line)

Answer (score 0):

The two answers above and a bit of searching allowed me to find a formula that worked.  I'll put it here for posterity, because questions with no final outcome are a pain for future readers.

```
=SUMPRODUCT( (INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,3)=C4) * (INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,1)="PTFBL") * INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,4):INDEX(LoansToApril2013,0,6))
```

This totals up values in columns 4-6 of the LoansToApril2013 range, where the value in column 3 equals the value in C4 (a.k.a. "the cell to the left of this one with the formula") AND the value in column 1 is "PTFBL".

Despite appearances, it isn't multiplying anything by anything else.  I found an explanation on [this page](http://www.consultdmw.com/excel-sumproduct-function.htm), but basically the asterisks are adding criteria to the function.  Note that criteria are enclosed in their own brackets, while the range isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use names ranges you need to use INDIRECT for the Index commands.

I used that formula to check for conditions in two columns, and then SUM the results in a table which has 12 columns for the months (the column is chosen by a helper cell which is 1 to 12 [L4]).

So you can do if:

**Dept (1 column name range [C6]) = Sales [D6]; 
Region (1 column name range [C3]) = USA [D3]; 
SUM figures in the 12 column monthly named range table [E7] for that 1 single month [L4] for those people/products/line item**

Just copy the formula across your report page which has columns 1-12 for the months and you get a monthly summary report with 2 conditions.

**=SUMPRODUCT( (INDEX(INDIRECT($C$6),0,1)=$D$6) * (INDEX(INDIRECT($C$3),0,1)=$D$3) * INDEX(INDIRECT($E7),0,L$4))**